# Windows Forms, компоненты

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли в C# при работе с визуальными приложениями, узнать какой именно компонент вызвал ту или иную функцию. 
Что бы разъяснить о чем идет речь, возьму для примера язык javascript. Там при передаче в функцию переменной this в функции появляется возможность работать с функцией/компонентов/другим объектом, вызвавшим ее, как с ссылкой.
 
Пример:

```
WhatCalledMe(el)
{
    alert(el.id);
}
</script>
<img id="header" onclick="WhatCalledMe(this)">
```

Выдаст: "header".

Пробовал работать с "object sender" и ничего оттуда не получается вытянуть.

Comment: Что именно не получилось вытянуть из sender?

Comment: Ооочень хотелось бы имя компонента.

Comment: так "имя компонента" - это ж наверное неотъемлемый атрибут sender'a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простенький пример.

В обработчик нажатия кнопки запишите следующее:

```
MessageBox.Show((sender as Control).Name);
```

Но, возможно, для индикации будет более удобен параметр Tag. Или иной способ, в зависимости от задачи.